# Create FactoryBot User with has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-5.2

## Background:

I am trying to create a FactoryBot object which is related with has_one/belongs_to

```
 User has_one Car

 Car has_one Style

 Style has an attribute {style_number:"1234"}
```

## Question

My controller references user, user has_one Car, Car has_one Style, and I need to set these values within FactoryBot.

How do I create a User, who also has a Car object, that has a Style object?

I read the documentation https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

However, I am not understanding how they recommend doing this. Figured out, I need to nest the three objects, but confused on the syntax.

## Controller

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :set_steps
before_action :setup_wizard    

include Wicked::Wizard

def show
    @user = current_user
    @form_object = form_object_model_for_step(step).new(@user)
    render_wizard 
end

private

def set_steps
    if style_is_1234
        self.steps = car_steps.insert(1, :style_car)                
    else
        self.steps = car_steps
    end
end

def style_is_1234
    if params.dig(:form_object, :style_number)
        (params.dig(:form_object, :style_number) & ["1234"]).present?
    else
        (current_user.try(:car).try(:style).try(:style_number) & ["1234"]).present?
    end
end

def car_steps
    [:type,:wheel, :brand]
end
```

## Rspec Test

#### Factory :User

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user, class: User do
    first_name { "John" }
    last_name  { "Doe" }
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password { "somepassword" }
    password_confirmation { "some password"}
  end
end
```

#### Before method

```
 before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
      sign_in user
```

### Test

User needs to be signed in and User.car.style.style_number needs to be set to "1234"

```
context "Requesting with second step CarStyle" do 
            it "should return success"  do
              get :show, params: { :id => 'car_style' }
              expect(response.status).to eq 200
            end
          end
```

Currently this test fails because User.Car.Style.style_number is not set to "1234".

#### Trial 1 (https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot_rails/issues/232)

```
FactoryBot.define do
      factory :user, class: User do
        first_name { "John" }
        last_name  { "Doe" }
        email { Faker::Internet.email }
        password { "somepassword" }
        password_confirmation { "some password"}
        car
      end
    end

FactoryBot.define do
      factory :car, class: Car do
        make { "Holden" }
        model  { "UTE" }
      end
    end


FactoryBot.define do
      factory :style, class: Style do
        color { "blue" }
        for_car

        trait :for_car do
          association(:styable, factory: :car)
        end
      end
    end
```

### Error from trail 1

> SystemStackError:
>           stack level too deep

### Trail 2

I tried srng's recommendation

EDIT: For a polymorphic association try;

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :car, class: Car do
    make { "Holden" }
    model  { "UTE" }
    association :stylable, factory: :style
  end
end
```

and got error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Stylable must exist

I think this is a rails 5 issue. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24518

However, I would like to keep my code with the adding the optional:true.  Any way to do this?

### Trail 3

```
FactoryBot.define do
   factory :car, class: Car do
     make { "Holden" }
     model  { "UTE" }
     after(:create) do |car|
        create(:style, stylable: car)
     end
   end
 end
```

Tried Srng's second recommendation and although it worked for him, I got a slightly different error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
>           Validation failed: User must exist

Answer (score 1):

In order to create dependent Factories you have to create a factory for each model, and then just add the dependent `Model` name to your factory, ie.

```
    FactoryBot.define do
      factory :user, class: User do
        first_name { "John" }
        last_name  { "Doe" }
        email { Faker::Internet.email }
        password { "somepassword" }
        password_confirmation { "some password"}
        car
      end
    end

FactoryBot.define do
      factory :car, class: Car do
        make { "Holden" }
        model  { "UTE" }
        style
      end
    end


FactoryBot.define do
      factory :style, class: Style do
        color { "blue" }
      end
    end
```

EDIT:
Relevant code;

```
# Factories
FactoryBot.define do
      factory :user, class: User do
        first_name { "John" }
        last_name  { "Doe" }
        email { Faker::Internet.email }
        password { "somepassword" }
        password_confirmation { "some password"}
        after(:create) do |user|
          user.car ||= create(:car, :user => user)
        end
      end
    end

  factory :style, class: Style do
    style_number { "Blue" }
  end

  factory :car, class: Car do
    name { "Holden" }
    trait :style do
      association :stylable, factory: :style
    end
end

#models
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :style, as: :styleable
end

class Style < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :styleable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :car
end

# Migrations - The belongs_to is the only important one
class CreateStyles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :styles do |t|
      t.string :style_number
      t.belongs_to :stylable, polymorphic: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateCars < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :cars do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: When I try the above, ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:, Validation failed: Stylable must exist, NOTE: Style has a polymorphic association with Car. Style has stylable_type, and Stylable_id.  Any thing special I need to do?

Comment: tried your example and get same error:       
      ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
        Validation failed: Stylable must exist

Comment: See changed answer, I've tested it locally on mine and got no errors so it is being created. I'm not sure about the mass of private methods you've got though.

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: Yes, what do you models look like? are you using the new optional parameter in the model?

Comment: I realized I got a slightly different error, User must exist now.

Comment: Hm, well I deleted all the example I coded, and when I just rewrote them it suddenly broke... Now I've got it back but with a different solution. I'll post all the relevant code. I didn't include the user because the polymorphic Style -> Car relationship is the one giving trouble.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189556/discussion-between-srng-and-user2012677).

Comment: Final adjustment. The user wasn't being created because it was silently failing in the factory. The 'car' being passed in the factory block is an unpermitted parameter. I blanked and reckoned there was a column in your User for a car_id. Dunno. 

The new Factory for User creates the user, and then in an After(:create) block will create a new Car attached to said user, which in turn has it's style. Hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

There can be an another way of attaining this using a transient block in the Factory.
Hope the below snippet may help you to explore in new way.

*Note: This is not tested.*

```
## To Create a user in test case
# create(:user) # defaults to 1234 style number
# create(:user, car_style_number: 5678)

DEFAULT_STYLE_NUMBER = 1234

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    transient do
      car_style_number { DEFAULT_STYLE_NUMBER }
    end

    first_name { "John" }
    last_name  { "Doe" }
    email { Faker::Internet.email }

    after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
      user.car = create(:car, car_style_number: evaluator.car_style_number, user: user)
    end
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :car do
    transient do
      car_style_number { DEFAULT_STYLE_NUMBER }
    end

    make { "Holden" }
    model  { "UTE" }
    after(:create) do |car, evaluator|
      car.style = create(:style, style_number: evaluator.car_style_number, car: car)
    end
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :style do
    style_number { DEFAULT_STYLE_NUMBER }
  end
end
```